# Does a refugee need a visa to visit Mexico?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, mexico, refugees

I am a refugee, I have a Italian travel document and Permesso Di Soggiorno and Carta Di Identità. I would like to travel to Mexico.
Do I need a visa?

Comment: To know the country you are citizen of would help, probably.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Mexico, not Morocco.

Comment: @gerrit Doh! Sorry, the question remains the same though.

Comment: @deviantfan Why do you think so? Without being sure, it looks as if citizenship is irrelevant if you want to enter Mexico with a refugee travel document.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo While I can find tha refugee travel documents can replace a passport, I also found a apparently exhaustive list of groups not requiring a *visa*, and here there is no such exception. Either citizenship may help, or applying for a visa.

Comment: @deviantfan In many countries, the moment you use a passport or other documentation from your origin country you risk losing your status as a refugee.

Comment: @SJuan76 So what do you suggest if they ask from which country he was, before fleeing? Lying? I don't think so.

Comment: @deviantfan If they ask him were he is from, he should tell it. But when he is asked to provide his ID/travel documents and produces the passport from the country he is fleeing from, there could be bad consequences. And of course he will not enter Mexico (or the plane) without some form of ID, so he should use his Italian documents for that.

Comment: `But when he is asked to provide his ID/travel documents and produces the passport from the country he is fleeing from` We agree that this would not be good.

Comment: @deviantfan we're losing the core question. Does the asker need a visa or does Mexico allow anyone with refugee status visa free entry? Or does Mexico require visas for some refugees and not others, in which case on what criteria?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.